# making a box with Header

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a box with Header and I want some text inside the box. Below is what I want:

[image]

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: add border to the text

Comment: Please provide at least some of your code so we can help.

Comment: @Dineshkarthik how would a border to the text solve anything? its background color for the title that needs to be added and span the entire box width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.main-box{
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.box-title{
    background-color:#000;
    padding:10px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:600;
}
.box-content{
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
.box-msg{
    font-weight:600;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-box">
    <div class="box-title">
        Your order has been submitted
    </div>
    <div class="box-content">
        <p class="box-msg">Thank you for your order.</p>
        <p>Transaction #:</p>
        <p>Transaction Date:</p>
        <p>Name:</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
Please try the HTML and CSS code below in your file.

<style>
.main-box{
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.box-title{
    background-color:#000;
    padding:10px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:600;
}
.box-content{
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
.box-msg{
    font-weight:600;
}
</style>

<div class="main-box">
    <div class="box-title">
        Your order has been submitted
    </div>
    <div class="box-content">
        <p class="box-msg">Thank you for your order.</p>
        <p>Transaction #:</p>
        <p>Transaction Date:</p>
        <p>Name:</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: An anwser without explanation is considered low-quality. An anwser always must contain enough explanation of what you did and how your solution works. The reason is, that others can follow your solution understand it and reproduce it. `try this code` therefor is low quality as it missing the explanation and therefor all teaching value. Please add a sufficient explanation of your solution to meet the SO guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

The easy and clean solution is to give the heading a full width of the box.

In my snippet i used `padding: 15px;`. To counter it for the header I have to add a negative margin equal the padding for top left and right `margin: -15px -15px 0 -15px;`.

I adress the header with the `:first-child` selector. to have the full width of the abckground color, I use: `width: calc(100% + padding left+right);`

```css
.textBox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}

.textBox :first-child {
  padding: 5px 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: calc(100% + 15px);
  margin: -15px -15px 0 -15px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="textBox">
  <p>Your order has been submitted</p>
  <h3>Thank you for your order.</h3>
  <p>Transaction #:</p>
  <p>Transaction Date:</p>
  <p>Name:</p>
</div>
```